# How register iOS 9 beta device

Tags: ios, udid, iphone-developer-program, beta

Rightnow I've installed iOS 9 beta only on my iPhone but now I want to install it on an iPhone of a friend to test Apple Watch apps on his watch.
How can I register his UDID or E-Mail to download the beta?

Answer (score 0):

developer.apple.com -> Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles -> Devices

Comment: Thanks, where can he download the beta after I added his UDID.

Comment: with your login credentials on developer.apple.com or [https://imzdl.com](https://imzdl.com)